# WCF object serialization using attribute

Tags: c#, wcf

I am new to this stuff. I am using WCF in C#. Suppose you have a WebService which returns entity A having fields aa and bb

This entity can be represented using:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.ns.com")]
public partial class A{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public bool Aa;  
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public bool Bb;
}
```

When i call the WS, it generates the response xml

```
<A>
   <Aa></Aa>
   <Bb><Bb>
</A>
```

I need it to generate the output rather like this:

```
<a aa="" bb=""/>
```

How do i do this?

Comment: Try using like following code -  `[XmlAttribute("aa")] public bool Aa; `

Answer (score 0):

Default behaviour of WCF is to use the DataContractSerializer. This is a serializer that looks for a completely different set of attributes for property annotations.

You will need to tell WCF to use the XmlSerializer instead of the default. This is all documentet here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-the-xmlserializer-class

Comment: Thank you. This works. I have another question. My service returns a response object EntityA. However, in the XML response, i see that EntityA is nested like this: <EntityAResponse>
   <EntityAResult>
   </EntityAResult>
</EntityAResponse>

I want to remove the Response and Result Elements

Comment: @DesiBoyzZ WCF is using SOAP and will produce SOAP messages. You might want to look into WCF a little deeper. You should also reconsider how important it is for you to control the message layer. Maybe what the XML looks like is irrelevant as long as the system using your service can deserialize the messages.

Comment: I do not have control on the system which deserializes the message and the existing system does not understand the message when it's wrapped inside a result/response element. But anyway i found a way to do it using MessageContract and setting the IsWrapped property to false. It works now. Thank you for your answer